# 0/1 Knapsack with Minimum Cost

Tags: dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

The famous `0/1` knapsack problem focuses on getting the maximum cost/value in the given `Weight (W)`.

The code for the above is this ::

```
n = cost_array / weight_array size
INIT :: fill 0th col and 0th row with value 0
for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
            for (int j=1; j<=W; j++) {
                if (weight[i-1] <= j) {
                    dp[i][j] = Math.max(dp[i-1][j], dp[i-1][j - weight[i-1]] + cost[i-1]);
                }else {
                    dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j];
                }
            }
        }
```

Ans :: `dp[n][W]`

**NEW  Problem** :: So, here we are calculating the maximum cost/value. But what if I want to find the minimum cost/value (Its still bounded knapsack only).

I think the problem boils down how I do the `INIT` step above. As in the loop I think it will remain same with the only difference of `Math.max` becoming `Math.min`

I tried the `INIT` step with `Infinity`, `0` etc but am not able to build the iterative solution.
How can we possibly do that?

Comment: Just convert every weight to the negative number and don't change the algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing answer as mentioned by @radovix

- Convert every weight to negative number and write the same algorithm.

Comment: Hi, could you share me the last version of the code? I couldn't implement it and it is eating my brain..

Answer (score 0):

here's an efficient algorithm for your problem written in JS (minimal-cost maximal knapsacking) with time complexity O(nC) and space complexity O(n+C) instead of the obvious solution with space complexity O(nC) with a DP matrix.
Given a knapsack instance (I, p,w, C), the goal of the MCMKP (Minimum-Cost Maximal Knapsack Packing) is to find a maximal knapsack packing S⊂I that minimizes the profit of selected items

```js
    const knapSack = (weights, prices, target, ic) => {
      if (weights.length !== prices.length) {
        return null;
      }
      let weightSum = [0],
      priceSum = [0];
      for (let i = 1; i < weights.length; i++) {
        weightSum[i] = weights[i - 1] + weightSum[i - 1];
        priceSum[i] = prices[i - 1] + priceSum[i - 1];
      }
      let dp = [0],
      opt = Infinity;
      for (let i = 1; i <= target; i++) dp[i] = Infinity;
      for (let i = weights.length; i >= 1; i--) {
        if (i <= ic) {
          const cMax = Math.max(0, target - weightSum[i - 1]),
          cMin = Math.max(0, target - weightSum[i - 1] - weights[i - 1] + 1);
          let tmp = Infinity;
          for (let index = cMin; index <= cMax; index++) {
            tmp = Math.min(tmp, dp[index] + priceSum[i - 1]);
          }
          if (tmp < opt) opt = tmp;
        }
        for (let j = target; j >= weights[i - 1]; j--) {
          dp[j] = Math.min(dp[j], dp[j - weights[i - 1]] + prices[i - 1]);
        }
      }
      return opt;
    };
    
    knapSack([1, 1, 2, 3, 4],[3, 4, 6, 2, 1],5,4);
```

In the following code above, we define a critical item, as an item whose weight gives a tight upper bound on the smallest possible item left out of any feasible solution.
the index of the critical item, i.e., the index of the first item that exceeds the capacity, assuming all i ≤ ic
will be taken as well. opt is the optimal solution.
Observe that the items {1, . . . , i − 1} determine the remaining capacity of the knapsack
(which is given as cMax) that has to be filled using items from {i + 1, . . . , n}, whereas cMin is determined by to the fact that the packing has to be maximal and that item i is the smallest one taken out of the solution

Comment: Hi, I really didn't get what ic is doing. could you explain in details, please?
For example, I have prices = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30] and weights = [200, 200, 500, 250, 300] .
I give capacity as 700 so the target, but which value should I give to ic so that I can have minimum value with filled capacity  = 35